# Json path for find key by regex

Tags: json, regex, jsonpath

I have a json data:

```
{
  "id": 101,
  "type": "test",
  "data": {
    "value1": "dog",
    "name1": "A",
    "value2": "pig",
    "name2": "B",
    "value3": "cat",
    "name3": "C"
  }
}
```

I want to apply JSONPath to it to only return results with key have prefix = `value*` in `data`.

The expected result is :

```
[
  {
    "dog",
    "pig",
    "cat",
  }
]
```

Which way to filter json key by regex in JSONPath expression?

Answer (score 1):

Is you json dta is fix, if yes then you can go for below without using regex

$.data.[value1,value2,value3]

Comment: Thank @amy, but the value is not fix, it can be 
`$.data.[value1,value2,value3,value4 ...]`